# dealing with "Javascript is currently disabled. Javascript is required..." in Python requests

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests

I am automating sending my transcripts out as I apply to schools for online undergrad CS classes, then online master's CS. I'd rather do it the correct way with requests instead of the cheesy xdotool where it takes over my screen.

My first request is:

```
import requests
mysession = requests.Session()

url = "https://hccadvisor.hccfl.edu/WebAdvisor/WebAdvisor"
first = mysession.get(url)

In [24]: first.content


'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">\n<html>\n<head>\n<script language="Javascript" src="./javascript/WebAdvisor_scripts.js"></script>\n<noscript>\n
<h1>Javascript is currently disabled. Javascript is required for WebAdvisor functionality and must be enabled before proceeding.</h1>
\n</noscript>\n</head>\n<body onload="javascript:setWindowHTML(\'\', \'\');">\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

How can I get this request to work?

Thank you

Comment: You are talking about running javascript, which means you need to automate a browser.  I'd recommend looking into WebDriver.

Comment: that's what I was wondering, thanks

Comment: regular google webdriver or selenium webdriver?